# Get the monday of a given week and year in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to find the Monday date for a given week and year.

Currently I have the following but for week 15 year 2020 it's giving me 4/8 and it should be 4/6.

```
function getDateOfWeek(weekNumber, year) {
            return new Date(year, 0, 1 + ((weekNumber - 1) * 7));
        }
```

Comment: What is your definition of "first week of the year"? E.g. : the week containing the first of january, or the first week of at least 4 days, or the first week containing a Monday? Which is the first day of the week? Monday, Sunday?

Comment: Monday should be the first day of the week. Week 15 should be 4/6/2020 which is a monday. That would mean 12/30/2019 was week 1 of 2020.

Comment: _"To calculate the date of the start of a given ISO8601 week (which will always be a Monday)..."_ - It's all in the accepted answer.